# Reset Bootstrap modal params after initialization

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modals allow you to [pass options through Javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) to do things such as make your modal not closable using `backdrop: "static"`.

However, once you initialize a modal without any params `$('#myModal').modal();` and then try to call it again this time with different params `$('#myModal2').modal({backdrop:"static"});` the modal is still initialized with no params, in this case it is still closable even though I called it again with the `backdrop: "static"` option.

Is there a way to reinitialize or change the paramaters of a Bootstrap modal once it has been called?

Here is a snippet showing the issue:

```js
$('body').on('click','#static',function() {
    $('#myModal').modal({backdrop:"static"});
});

$('body').on('click','#modal',function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a id="static" href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" >Static Modal</a>
<a id="modal" href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn">Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
   Foo
</div>
```

1. Click "Static Modal" and a modal appears that cant be closed.
2. Refresh
3. Click "Modal" and a modal appears that can be closed, close it
4. Click "Static Modal", now a modal appears that **can** be closed, when it shouldn't

Comment: Can be reproduced from just step 3 and 4 for me.

Comment: @TimLewis Yah sorry I put step 1 (and therefore 2) to show what it is _supposed_ to do in case someone is unfamiliar with Bootstrap, I suppose that is confusing though.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I'm looking more into this now. Has something to do with using the same modal, which I've never done like this before.

Comment: Sheesh... I got nothing. Been testing for the past 40 minutes, came up blank. It seems that after the first initialization using `.modal({ });` you can't re-initialize it. I tried applying different `data-` attributes on both the buttons and the modal itself, no luck. I even tried "resetting" the modal (by removing it from the dom and replacing it with a clone of itself before modal initialization) and calling `.modal({ })` on this, but it still didn't work... I guess long story short, use different modals.

Comment: Check this bootply : http://www.bootply.com/exnPaWii88. Its not the best way but it will work. Its working fine, i can explain if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this Bootstrap Modal plugin to solve your problem quickly:

http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Back to the question here, by using above plugin, you should be able to achieve by these lines:

```js
    BootstrapDialog.show({
      title: 'To close or not to close it, this is a question.',
      message: 'Click buttons below and see how the closing behaviors change.',
      buttons: [{
        label: 'Modal closable',
        action: function(dialog) {
          dialog.setClosable(true);
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Modal unclosable',
        action: function(dialog) {
          dialog.setClosable(false);
        }
      }]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
```

This is more like a javascript program, no html markups needed, clean and neat.

One more example in case you would like to change the closing behaviors outside any closures of the dialog (modal) definition:

```js
// Prepare a dialog instance but do not open it at this moment
var dialog = new BootstrapDialog();

// Buttons clicked
$('#btn-closable').click(function() {
  dialog.setClosable(true);
  dialog.setTitle('This modal is CLOSABLE');
  dialog.setMessage('Just close the modal as usual.');
  dialog.open();
});
$('#btn-unclosable').click(function() {
  dialog.setClosable(false);
  dialog.setMessage(function(dialogInstance) {
    var $button = $('<button>Modal Closable</button>');
    $button.click(function() {
      dialogInstance.setClosable(true);
    });

    return $button;
  });
  dialog.setTitle('This modal is UNCLOSABLE');
  dialog.open();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<button id="btn-closable">
  Modal Closable
</button>
<button id="btn-unclosable">
  Modal Unclosable
</button>
```

The 2nd example also demonstrates a handy way to dynamically change modal title and message, and the message can also be set as a closure, which offers you opportunities of building fancy things inside the modal, in JAVASCRIPT fashion.

Answer (score 0):

`$.extend( $( '#myModal2' ).data( 'bs.modal' ).options, { backdrop: "static" } );`

or

`$.extend( $( '#myModal2' ).data( 'modal' ).options, { backdrop: "static" } );`